# Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjiVQ.png)

Why customer is not show name of the order?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to provide us more than a js-error. What version of wordpress? What version of WooCommerce? On which explicit action throw up the error? Maybe add some Screenshots or steps to understand your problem.